# Find-Module is able to find a module in Powershell 5.1 (Windows), but not in Powershell 7.0.2 (Core)

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-core

I have some pester unit tests that involve calling `Find-Module` on a local PS repository. When I tried to run the on PS 7.0.2 that method finds nothing.

Please, observe:

**PS 5.1**

```
C:\> "$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"
5.1.17763.1007
C:\> $Name = '_KYKYPY3A_'
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"
ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...etPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource], Exception
C:\> $PSRepoDir = "$env:TEMP\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r$Name"
C:\> dir $PSRepoDir


    Directory: C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        7/18/2020  11:27 AM          15758 m_KYKYPY3A_.0.0.0.1.nupkg


C:\> Register-PSRepository "r$Name" -SourceLocation $PSRepoDir -PublishLocation $PSRepoDir -InstallationPolicy Trusted
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
r_KYKYPY3A_               Trusted              C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_


C:\> Find-Module -Name "m$Name" -Repository "r$Name" -AllVersions -Verbose
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'r_KYKYPY3A_', Location =
'C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'r_KYKYPY3A_'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_' and
PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'm_KYKYPY3A_'.

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
0.0.0.1    m_KYKYPY3A_                         r_KYKYPY3A_          Test


C:\> Unregister-PSRepository "r$Name"
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"
ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...etPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource], Exception
C:\>
```

Everything works as expected. At the end of this run my test repository is unregistered.

Now I am going to repeat exactly the same steps on PS 7.0.2:

**PS 7.0.2**

```
C:\> "$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"
7.0.2
C:\> $Name = '_KYKYPY3A_'
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"
ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.PowerShel…ts.GetPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource], Exception
C:\> $PSRepoDir = "$env:TEMP\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r$Name"
C:\> dir $PSRepoDir


    Directory: C:\Users\mkharitonov\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---           7/18/2020 11:27 AM          15758 m_KYKYPY3A_.0.0.0.1.nupkg

C:\> Register-PSRepository "r$Name" -SourceLocation $PSRepoDir -PublishLocation $PSRepoDir -InstallationPolicy Trusted
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"

Name                      InstallationPolicy   SourceLocation
----                      ------------------   --------------
r_KYKYPY3A_               Trusted              C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_

C:\> Find-Module -Name "m$Name" -Repository "r$Name" -AllVersions -Verbose
VERBOSE: Repository details, Name = 'r_KYKYPY3A_', Location = 'C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_'; IsTrusted = 'True'; IsRegistered = 'True'.
VERBOSE: Using the provider 'PowerShellGet' for searching packages.
VERBOSE: Using the specified source names : 'r_KYKYPY3A_'.
VERBOSE: Getting the provider object for the PackageManagement Provider 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: The specified Location is 'C:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\fb22c60e-a0c5-48b3-953a-0b580c6a2f5e\r_KYKYPY3A_' and PackageManagementProvider is 'NuGet'.
VERBOSE: Total package yield:'1' for the specified package 'm_KYKYPY3A_'.
C:\> Unregister-PSRepository "r$Name"
C:\> Get-PSRepository "r$Name"
ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.PowerShel…ts.GetPackageSource:GetPackageSource) [Get-PackageSource], Exception
C:\>
```

Notice the difference - on PS 7.0.2 the `Find-Module` does not return the module, even though the verbose output indicates that it found it.

Now I am pretty certain there is something wrong with the module nupkg - I created it long ago and it is just being part of the pester tests as is. Here is the `tree` command output within it:

```
C:\TESTDATA\PACKAGES\KYKYPY3A\1
│   m_KYKYPY3A_.nuspec
│   m_KYKYPY3A_.psd1
│   m_KYKYPY3A_.psm1
│   [Content_Types].xml
│
├───package
│   └───services
│       └───metadata
│           └───core-properties
│                   281a93dd3649425c8601e22381710a28.psmdcp
│
└───_rels
        .rels
```

Where:

```
C:\> cat TestData\Packages\KYKYPY3A\1\m_KYKYPY3A_.nuspec
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>m_KYKYPY3A_</id>
    <version>0.0.0.1</version>
    <authors>Test</authors>
    <owners>Test</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Test</description>
    <releaseNotes />
    <copyright>Test</copyright>
    <tags>PSModule PSIncludes_Function PSFunction_Use-ModuleFB22C60E PSFunction_Write-HostIfNotVerboseFB22C60E PSCommand_Use-ModuleFB22C60E PSCommand_Write-HostIfNotVerboseFB22C60E</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

```
C:\> cat TestData\Packages\KYKYPY3A\1\m_KYKYPY3A_.psd1
@{
    RootModule        = "m_KYKYPY3A_.psm1"
    ModuleVersion     = "0.0.0.1"
    GUID              = "bceebfea-ec4b-4f6a-bf44-963eab0634dd"
    Author            = "Test"
    CompanyName       = "Test"
    Copyright         = "Test"
    Description       = "Test"
    NestedModules     = @()
    FunctionsToExport = @('Use-ModuleFB22C60E', 'Write-HostIfNotVerboseFB22C60E', 'Get-ElapsedSecondsStringFB22C60E')
}
```

```
C:\> cat 'TestData\Packages\KYKYPY3A\1\`[Content_Types`].xml'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"><Default Extension="rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" /><Default Extension="nuspec" ContentType="application/octet" /><Default Extension="psd1" ContentType="application/octet" /><Default Extension="psm1" ContentType="application/octet" /><Default Extension="psmdcp" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml" /></Types>
```

```
C:\> cat 'TestData\Packages\KYKYPY3A\1\package\services\metadata\core-properties\281a93dd3649425c8601e22381710a28.psmdcp'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><coreProperties xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties"><dc:creator>Test</dc:creator><dc:description>Test</dc:description><dc:identifier>m_KYKYPY3A_</dc:identifier><version>0.0.0.1</version><keywords>PSModule PSIncludes_Function PSFunction_Use-ModuleFB22C60E PSFunction_Write-HostIfNotVerboseFB22C60E PSCommand_Use-ModuleFB22C60E PSCommand_Write-HostIfNotVerboseFB22C60E</keywords><lastModifiedBy>NuGet, Version=2.8.60717.93, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null;Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0;.NET Framework 4.5</lastModifiedBy></coreProperties>
```

```
C:\> cat 'TestData\Packages\KYKYPY3A\1\_rels\.rels'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/manifest" Target="/m_KYKYPY3A_.nuspec" Id="R722bc8612cea44ba" /><Relationship Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="/package/services/metadata/core-properties/281a93dd3649425c8601e22381710a28.psmdcp" Id="R5f6122b4dbb64549" /></Relationships>
```

There must be a flaw in one of these files or maybe something is missing to satisfy PS 7.0.2, because other than that the modules in PS 7.0.2 seem to work just fine.

Comment: Maybe check file encoding of the module, manifest, resource files, etc.  [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7) might shed some insights.  Worth a mention.  Good luck.

Comment: I would like at the versions of PowerShellGet and OneGet running in Windows PowerShell and Powershell Core. They are likely different. I have had issues with some versions and interaction between versions of the two modules. A while back I removed both from my PowerShell 7 environment, reinstalled them and the issues went away.

Comment: This seems to be a bug with newer versions of PowerShellGet, see [GitHub - Find-Module -AllVersions does not produce output](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGetv2/issues/604)

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try adding `-AllowPrerelease`

```
Find-Module -Name "m$Name" -Repository "r$Name" -AllVersions -AllowPrerelease -Verbose
```